# Flutter web site takes time to show up

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

My simple web application takes 7 seconds to 9 seconds to start.
I've added a loading view but I think that is not normal... I've tried also with the base app created by default. Tried with different browser, connection and devices.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are;

Try to generate a light house performance report. Then find out what makes your web app to load slowly.

Try some alternatives for the heavy files like images, assets by resizing the image.

Learn more on how to improve the light house performance through (https://web.dev/lighthouse-best-practices/). You can also find lot of resources, topics, hands-on codelab to learn new skills.

I hope this helps you to reduce the web app load time, if so reply back how did you improved the performance and loaded the web app instantly.